# How to make Horizontal Bar in pygal with labels on y?

Tags: pygal

Something like [this](http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/documentation/types/bar.html), but without legend and with labels on y.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I've used to make a horizontal bar with pygal:

```
bar_chart = pygal.HorizontalBar(show_legend=False)
bar_chart.title = "Title"
bar_chart.add("", [1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3])
bar_chart.x_labels = ("the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over")
```

It produced a graph like this:
[image: pygal horizontal example]

Comment: How can I make each label with different color instead of one as shown?

Comment: have you tried http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/value.html?highlight=color ?